# Start Git Bash from users directory

Tags: windows, bash, git, mingw

I am running the latest version of `git` on Windows. When I start `Git Bash` (Running `MINGW32`) from my start menu it starts git from my users home directory. When I pin the window to the task bar and then click on it from the task bar it starts in the `C:\` directory. Is there a way where I can get it to always start from my users directory?

Comment: Did you found a solution?

Comment: No, but does seem to be displaying from my home directory now...

Comment: Here is a solution from stack overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19916670/how-to-launch-a-git-bash-window-with-particular-working-directory-using-a-script

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your .bashrc file:

`cd <location>;`

If the .bashrc file doesn't exist, create one in your home folder. For me, it's C:\Users\username\

Save .bashrc and open Git Bash.

Comment: That isn't working. I tried `cd ~` and `cd /c/Users/rnaddy` neither worked. I also closed and reopened bash.

Comment: if I run `source ~/.bashrc` it seems to work, just not on startup

Comment: got it, I had to add it to `~/.bash_profile`

Comment: This is a heavy-handed approach.  How would you then open bash in any other directory?